# Angular Reactive Form - convert email address to lowercase on submit

Tags: angular, email-validation, lowercase, angular-reactive-forms

In my reactive form I allow users to enter email addresses where the text before the '@' can contain uppercase characters. However I want to convert say 'DAve@gmail.com' (which is valid) to 'dave@gmail.com' onSubmit.

I have tried creating a separate function, which converts the input to lowercase within onSubmit, tried to call toLowerCase() on the getter, and call toLowerCase() within the FormBuilder, however they all cause errors or the form is invalid.

I'm sure it's something simple but I'm a little stuck...

FORMBUILDER

```
this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    email: [this.user.email, [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$')]]
});
```

GETTER

```
get email() {
        return this.firstFormGroup.get('email');
    }
```

ONSUBMIT

```
this.user.lastName = this.firstFormGroup.controls['email'].value;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `toLowerCase()` in value of form controls as

```
this.user.lastName = this.firstFormGroup.controls['email'].value.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: I had tried this as well but it won't let me submit the form, as I assume it think it's invalid. I'm using Angular Stepper as well so maybe that if effecting it. Thanks for pointer. I think I'll just convert it to lowercase on the backend instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert while typing you can use `(input)`

```
<input (input)="loginForm.controls.userName.setValue(loginForm.controls.userName.value.toLowerCase())"
          formControlName="userName" id="userName">
```